# Run php composer.phar from wampstack

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line, wamp

I want to run php composer.phar update from my apache2/htdocs/reuzze folder.
My php file is located in wampstack/php and my folder i want to update in composer in wampstack/apache2/htdocs/reuzze.

I have tried doing this:

```
php ../apache2/htdocs/reuzze composer.phar update
```

But I get the error 'Could not open input file : ../apache2/htdocs/reuzze

Whats the rigt link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tell windows how to find the php.exe, so you need to add it to the PATH.

My favoured solution is to create a little `.cmd` file that I can run from anywhere that temporarily adds the PHP folder to the PATH when I run it from a command window.

So create a `.cmd` file lets say called `addphp.cmd` put it in a folder that is already on your PATH. This is the code.

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\wampstack\php
```

Now when you run that command file it will add the folder that contains your PHP.EXE to the path just for the life of the command windows.

Now CD to whichever folder you want to run a PHP CLI script from eg `/apache2/htdocs/reuzze`. Run addphp.cmd. Then do

```
php composer.phar update
```

And it should find the php processor with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply either copy or move `composer.phar` to the directoy where you need it? Either way, you can also simply use it from a different directory (assuming you are in the directory where you want to update your dependencies):

```
php ../apache2/htdocs/reuzze/composer.phar update
```

Comment: but the php doesn't work, that's why I use it from the php folder